# IOS: app with a big amount of data

Tags: ios, database, xcode

In my app (for iPad) I want to use a large quanitity of data. It function in this way: if I select an argument in a row of a tableview I must show much text. The solution that I think to use for this app is a big file xml or more file xml to contain tis data. Is a correct way? or is there a best way to contain this data quantity of string? Where can I store this amount of data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take a look to Proxy Design pattern.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern

Actually small xml, and big xml should work but make care that your code design is good.